# Putting images in a simple parallel array with next previous buttons

Tags: javascript, java, html, arrays

I’m really new to JavaScript and trying to figure out a basic slide with pictures built in an array. Like you click next and previous to get new images.

How can I do that? Here is what I have so far.

```
<html>
<body>

<script>

imgArray = new Array(
“image”,
“image”
“image”); 

x=1
y=2; 

function move{
y = y+xflip; 
if (y>x)
{y = 1;}
if (y==0)
{y = x; 
document.images[2].src = img[y-1];}

</script>

<input type=“button” value=“Prev” name=“buttonp” onclick=“slide(-1)”>
<input type=“button” value=“Next” name=buttonb” onclock=“slide(1)”>

<img src=“image1”>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You have mistake in your script like `function move()` and please use `var` before you define new variable.

Comment: also the onclick event is calling the function slide(), but in the js the function is called move (and as Victor said - you need to have the () after the function name in the js. also there is no feature in the js function to accept the arguments passed (either 1 or -1) in the onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

I like the jquery approach.
You could try something like this. You would need to add a bit extra logic for clicking previous at first go etc.

```
<button id=“buttonprev” type="button">Previous</button>
<button id=buttonforward”>Next</button>

<img id="preview" src="#" alt="your image" />

<script>
    var imgArray = ['image1.png', 'image2.png', 'image3.png'];
    var imgCount = 0;

    $("#buttonforward").on('click', function(event) {
      imgCount += 1;
      $('#preview').attr('src', imgArray[imgCount]);
    });

    $("#buttonprev").on('click', function(event) {
      imgCount -= 1;
      $('#preview').attr('src', imgArray[imgCount]);
    });
</script>
```